# Amazon Lex doesn't passes the conversation between user and Lex to amazon connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

In this [Presentation Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKnOHtHcgVE) from Yaseer (Amazon Connect). He Demostrated that Amazon Lex Passes the conversion that happened between the user and Lex bot to the Amazon Connect contact Center agent.

However I dont receive the conversion data in Amazon connect streams api. I do get only the session Attributes.

> How do I get the full conversation that happened btw the Lex bot and User while connect to the agent in amazon connect contact center ?

Any thoughts would be much helpful. Thanks!

PS - There is not similar question exists that I could find helpful for me, so created a new one.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [source code for that demo](https://www.connectdemo.com/references/lexLambdaRideService.html).  It uses appendTranscript to build the full transcript of the Lex chatbot interaction.

Comment: I was searching for this demo everywhere, couldn't find it. Thanks a ton !